# check for a substring in a string before the first comma

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a set of strings separated by `,`
example:

```
abc,defg,ijkl

pqrs,tu,vv

,klmnop,qwe

aamn,nn,khhk
```

As you can see, the third line doesn't start with a substring. It starts with a comma.

Using regex how can I tell a string starts with a substring of a random length  before the first comma.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: is it a String array or are you  reading it from a file ?

Comment: Or just trim it? :/

Comment: @user3338391 - Or, for anybody who lands on this question that might be puzzled based on the answer you accepted:  In regex land, _not something_, for instance `[^,]` matches everything else but comma. In not sure of your definition of  _substring_, but within 7 bit ascii, any of these will match NUL, SOH, STX, ETX, EOT, ENQ, ACK, BEL, BS, TAB, LF, VT, FF, CR, SO, SI, DLE, DC1, DC2, DC3, DC4, NAK, SYN, ETB, CAN, EM, SUB, ESC, FS, GS, RS, US, DEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

```
^"[^"]+",
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Verifies the string starts with a substring
- Requires the substring to be any random length greater than zero

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/kE3bG5/1

**Sample text**

```
abc,defg,ijkl
pqrs,tu,vv
,klmnop,qwe
aamn,nn,khhk
```

**Sample Matches**

```
abc,
pqrs,
aamn,
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^,]+                    any character except: ',' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to my answer except that I don't (") around my strings, they are really like this: abc,defg,ijkl
pqrs,tu,vv
,klmnop,qwe
aamn,nn,khhk

Comment: Updated answer to work with your modified source text

Answer (score 1):

`(?m)^[^,\w]*\w.*?,.*`

Explained

```
 (?m)         # Multi-line mode
 ^            # Beginning of line
 [^,\w]*      # Optional Non- word nor comma
 \w           # Word
 .*?          # Optional anything
 ,            # Comma
 .*           # All to end of line
```